# Align first line between two minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I want to put my text on columns. On the first on, it will never be lot of things, like a date. On the second, it will be some text, and possibly multiple lines. I want to make the text on the left column always aligned with the first line to the second column. But I can't achieved it, even when there is only one line on the right column, the left one is not always aligned.

I tried all combinations of the `minipage` alignment (`[t]`, `[c]`, `[b]`). But it changed nothing.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\dateWidth}{4cm}
\newcommand{\textWidth}{12cm}

\renewcommand{\exp}[6]{

  \begin{minipage}[c]{\dateWidth}
    \flushright
    \footnotesize
    #1\\        % Date
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\textWidth}
    \footnotesize

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{
      \textbf{#2},
      \textsl{#3}.\\
      {#6} %
    }{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{
        \textbf{#2},  % Titre du poste
        \textsl{#3},  % Société
        {#4},   % Lieu
        {#5}.   % Contexte
      }{
        \textbf{#2},  % Titre du poste
        \textsl{#3},  % Société
        {#4},   % Lieu
        {#5}.\\ % Contexte
        {#6}  % Description
      }
    }
  \end{minipage}

}

\begin{document}

  \exp
    {2019 - 2020}
    {Lorem ipsum dolor}
    {sit amet}
    {consectetur adipiscing elit}
    {sed do eiusmod}
    {tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Commodo sed egestas
    egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod.
    Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
    et netus.}

  \exp
    {2015 - 2018}
    {Faucibus ornare suspendisse}
    {sed nisi lacus}
    {Morbi enim nunc}
    {faucibus a pellentesque}
    {}

\end{document}
```

In my real document, each `\exp` are under each other. I didn't achieved to do it in the example.

Comment: I'd like to encourage you to have a look at the `raster` library of `tcolorbox`. (Let me guess: your real document does not use the `standalone` class, or uses this class with different options. This would explain why you get different arrangements.)

Comment: If you replace `standalone` with `article` and use `[t]` for both `minipage`s, you get the desired results. If you don't, please clarify your question. It is important to actually show us the problem you have and not a different one. If you don't actually use `standalone` (and it gives different results than your "real document"), don't use it here. (Generally speaking, `article` is the preferred document class for MWEs here when the class doesn't matter for the question.)

Comment: Yes, my real document do not use the standalone class. I'll have a look to the `raster` library. It seems I did not tried all possible combinations. I just tried the `[t]` for both minipage, and it works as expected. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You want `\begin{minipage}[t]` and not `[c]`. But there's no need to use a `minipage` with `\raggedleft` for the date (note that `\flushright` is wrong anyway).

Here's a “purified” version of your code, where the width of the second minipage is so it fills the whole remaining space.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=18cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\dateWidth}{4cm}
\newcommand{\textWidth}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\textWidth{\the\dimexpr\textwidth-\dateWidth-0.5em\relax}}

\renewcommand{\exp}[6]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent
  \makebox[\dateWidth][r]{\footnotesize #1}\hfill % Date
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textWidth}
    \footnotesize
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{%
      \textbf{#2},
      \textsl{#3}.\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\par#6}%
    }{%
      \textbf{#2},  % Titre du poste
      \textsl{#3},  % Société
      {#4},   % Lieu
      {#5}.% Contexte
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\par#6}% Description
    }%
  \end{minipage}\par
}

\begin{document}

  \exp
    {2019 - 2020}
    {Lorem ipsum dolor}
    {sit amet}
    {consectetur adipiscing elit}
    {sed do eiusmod}
    {tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Commodo sed egestas
    egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod.
    Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
    et netus.}

  \exp
    {2015 - 2018}
    {Faucibus ornare suspendisse}
    {sed nisi lacus}
    {Morbi enim nunc}
    {faucibus a pellentesque}
    {}

\end{document}
```

Beware of spurious spaces! The `showframe` package is only for making the text block more evident.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you need to align both the `minipage` should be top align, if yes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\dateWidth}{4cm}
\newcommand{\textWidth}{12cm}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\renewcommand{\exp}[6]{
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\dateWidth}
    \flushright
    \footnotesize
    #1\\        % Date
  \end{minipage}}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\textWidth}
    \footnotesize

    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{
      \textbf{#2},
      \textsl{#3}.\\
      {#6} %
    }{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{
        \textbf{#2},  % Titre du poste
        \textsl{#3},  % Société
        {#4},   % Lieu
        {#5}.   % Contexte
      }{
        \textbf{#2},  % Titre du poste
        \textsl{#3},  % Société
        {#4},   % Lieu
        {#5}.\\ % Contexte
        {#6}  % Description
      }
    }
  \end{minipage}
}
}

\begin{document}

  \exp
    {2019 - 2020}
    {Lorem ipsum dolor}
    {sit amet}
    {consectetur adipiscing elit}
    {sed do eiusmod}
    {tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Commodo sed egestas
    egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod.
    Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
    et netus.}

  \exp
    {2015 - 2018}
    {Faucibus ornare suspendisse}
    {sed nisi lacus}
    {Morbi enim nunc}
    {faucibus a pellentesque}
    {}

\end{document}
```

Excuse me, if my understand is wrong...